# Window cancel in jsp. How to return to previous page. JS

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

My class controller in JAVA:

```
    public class Controller extends HttpServlet {

    private Chooser chooser = Chooser.INSTANCE;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(req, resp);
    }

    private void processRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        try {
            String page = chooser.chooseCommand(req.getParameter("command")).execute(req, resp);
            req.getRequestDispatcher(page).forward(req, resp);
        } catch (ServletException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Next, class ENUM, that choose page:

```
public enum Chooser {

    INSTANCE;

    private Map<String, ICommand> commandMap = new HashMap<>();

    private Chooser() {

        // commands for profession
        commandMap.put("professions", new ProfessionCommand());
        commandMap.put("addProfession", new AddProfessionCommand());
        commandMap.put("saveProfession", new SaveProfessionCommand());
        commandMap.put("deleteProfession", new DeleteProfessionCommand());
        commandMap.put("editProfession", new EditProfessionCommand());

        public ICommand chooseCommand(String command) {
        return commandMap.get(command);
    }

}
```

Interface, icommand:

```
public interface ICommand {

    String execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse resp);

}
```

My class DeleteProfessionCommand:

```
public class DeleteProfessionCommand implements ICommand {

    private ApplicantDBProvider provider = ApplicantDBProvider.INSTANCE;

    @Override
    public String execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse resp) {

        try {
            Long professionId = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("id"));
            provider.deleteProfession(professionId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            request.setAttribute("error", e);
            return "pages/error.jsp";
        }

        return "controller?command=professions";
    }
}
```

In my jsp, when i want to delete row, i used this command:

```
<a href="controller?command=deleteProfession&id=${profession.getId()}">Delete</a>
```

My question:
When, i click delete, i want to get allert message, that tell me:
"Are you sure to delete", and buttons, "Yes", "No".
How to do this, i dont know. Because, i learn only java, and no more month .
Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with javascript, in your jsp the anchor tag for Delete

```
<a href="controller?command=deleteProfession&id=${profession.getId()}">Delete</a>
```

make these changes,

```
<a class="deleteAnchor" data-command="deleteProfession" data-id="${profession.getId()}" href="javascript:void(0);">Delete</a>
```

Then, add the below at the end of the your jsp,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.deleteAnchor').on('click', function(){
    // confirm will give you a 'ok' and 'cancel' button instead of yes or no
    // you can use one of the other libraries like bootbox to get a nice confirmation dialog box with 'yes' and 'no' buttons
    var result = confirm('Are you sure to delete?');
    if(result) {
        //Delete
        $.ajax({
            url: 'controller',
            data: {'command' : $(this).data('command'), 'id' : $(this).data('id')},
            success: function() {
                //Do something on success
            }
        });
    } else {
        //Dont delete
    }
});
</script>
```

You can refer [bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/) for better confirmation boxes